# Oracle - multiple databases on one server, connect issue

Tags: database, oracle, shutdown, ora-12514

I'm new in Oracle Database and so far I was using only MS SQL Server. I created two databases on my laptop (habit from MS), which is running Windows 8.

I stoped those two databases using SQL Plus and "shutdown normal" command. Before stoping those databases, I connected to them using "user/password@database_SID" syntax. After shutdown I can't choose which database I want to connect because when using "@Database_SID" I've got this error:

"ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor".

How can I define which database I want to connect whithout "@Database_SID" syntax?

Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: If you are running sqlplus on the server box, it used to be that you set your `ORACLE_SID` environment variable and then invoke sqlplus.

Comment: @user3313214:yes you need to check whether your listner is running or nt !! in oracle server export your sid,then type lsnrctl start

Comment: One thing to be aware of is that Oracle's definition of "database" is very different from SQL Server's definition of "database".  A SQL Server "database" is roughly equivalent logically to an Oracle schema.  Having two separate Oracle databases running on your laptop is generally not a good idea.  That means that you'll have two sets of background processes running, you'll have two separate SGA and PGA allocations in RAM, etc.  It would be much more equivalent in Oracle to have one database with two different schemas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Locally on your machine, you use IPC - Inter Process Communication to login to your database in order to do administrative work. (startup, shutdown, mount, etc)

```
C:\>set ORACLE_SID=DB1
C:\>sqlplus / as sysdba -- make sure you are member of group "ORA_DBA"
SQL>startup

C:\>set ORACLE_SID=DB2
C:\>sqlplus / as sysdba 
SQL>startup
```

ORA-12514 indicates the database has not registered with the listener because database status is *shutdown*

Note. The Windows Service `OracleService<SID>` can have status "Running", but the database can be stopped (shutdown)

There is no need to have two physical databases running on your laptop. Waste of resources. In Oracle terms you need two schemas.

Comment: Thank You, that was very useful. I realized that Oracle Database <> MS database after creation of second database.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the listener is running.

On Windows, Oracle seems to use the networking layer, even when connecting locally.